# Website is reached for too many URLs

Tags: php, joomla

We have shifted our website from php to Joomla but it's creating dynamic URLs and google indexing them.

Our website is currently reachable via all of these URLs:

- ww.w.example.com
- ww.example.com
- www.example.comwww.example.com
- www.example.comadfadfwww.example.com

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can anybody translate this to English, please?

Comment: please check htaccess file maybe it redirect all subdomain to domain name . or you set *.example.com to domain control panel.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question so that it now explains the background behind your question - your website is reachable by too many URLs. Next I fixed lots of formatting issues and grammer / spelling mistakes. I also added the list of URLs that reach your website to make your question easier to read quickly. I hope this helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check this one at first .The article is what you need.
https://joomlaseo.com/checklist/avoid-duplicate-url-s

Also i would recommend SH404SEF.
SH404SEF is probably the best known full SEO extension for Joomla.
It will help you a lot